# GraphQL gem with Rails, can't seem to find correct type definition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I've defined a UserType as such:

```
class Types::UserType < GraphQL::Schema::Object
  field :id, ID, null: false
  field :username, String, null: false
  field :full_name, String, null: true
end
```

Each of these fields exists on the Rails model, and pre 1.8 upgrade of the GraphQL Gem, I was able to use full_name in queries just fine.

When I run the query:

```
query {
  users {
    username
    id
    full_name
  }
}
```

I get: `"message": "Field 'full_name' doesn't exist on type 'User'",`

If I remove `full_name`, I get the data I expect. In what way am I approaching this incorrectly? For reference, my `QueryType` is defined as:

```
class Types::QueryType < GraphQL::Schema::Object
  # Add root-level fields here.
  # They will be entry points for queries on your schema.
  field :users, [UserType, null: true], null: false do
    argument :id, Integer, required: false
  end

  def users(**args)
    args[:id]
    if args[:id]
      User.where(id: args[:id])
    else
      User.all
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the issue is that `full_name` should be `fullName` in your query. With 1.8.x the fields in the schema are auto-camalized.

> Field and argument names should be underscored as a convention. They will be converted to camelCase in the underlying GraphQL type and be camelCase in the schema itself.

-- http://graphql-ruby.org/type_definitions/objects.html